# Identity Server 4 Authentication Too Slow

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, identityserver4

I just tried out the samples for identity server 4 in here for .Net Core

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples

On the QuickStarts I tested the ImplicitFlowAuthentication.

The thing is, it takes very long just to reach the login page on the identity server app sometimes.

I'm testing this in the intranet of our company and I was looking for a solution to centralize authentication for all of our applications.

Out of the box I really like how flexible identity server 4 is but i don't understand why it takes more than 20 seconds to reach the identity server 4. Today It took less than a second to access it but yesterday it took almost a minute to login and logout using the sample solution.

On the other hand I already have working solution with Jwt authentication using a Web API but I have to deal with many customizations and handle how i store the token on the clients.

So there's 2 options for me.

Option 1: Go with identity server 4 and try to optimize it as much as possible.

Option 2: Stay with Jwt Web Api Authentication and try to secure it as much as possible.

If anyone can help me choose and why for my situation please do so. My aim is to allow users on our company intranet to access every single application without having to login every time and avoid duplicating data for each app. Also the users are validated against a LDAP and i saw IdentityServer4 also has an extension.

If there are more options please advice.

**EDIT**

For testing IS4, I ran it locally, as the only user and in debug mode. I'm actually trying to find out if IS4 has some configuration that might slow down performance

Comment: How can we help, when you don't provide information on your exact issue? Where is it slow? development system? production? how many users? How many requests? did you check network issues? did you customize it? Are you in debugging mode (F5 mode, visual studio)?

Comment: I just ran the sample locally as the only user in debug mode. What i'm trying to find out is if there is actually something on the application itself that slows redirection

Comment: Debug mode is much slower, but 20 seconds sounds excessive, 2-4 seconds are more realistic, 5-8 on first execution due to jitter. Detach the debugger (or Ctrl+F5)

Answer (score 1):

Just Install The Redis Server and Start it right before starting the main project
https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/2764

Comment: well, this fixed my problem with the adp angular template with separated IdentityServer.  This is also another alternative if installing Redis is not an option: https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/5708#issuecomment-703977488